# Subtracting days from current_timestamp() in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to get the timestamp that is exactly 10 days before the current timestamp in Hive. I can get the current timestamp using the function current_timestamp() in hive (I don't want to use unix_timestamp() here because its deprecated in recent versions of hive).
So, How do I get the timestamp which is exactly 10 days before the current timestamp? Any function like add_days available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `current_timestamp` to unix timestamp and subtract 10 days=10*86400 seconds. Then use `from_unixtime` to get the timestamp string.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp)-10*86400,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Note that [`unix_timestamp()` is being deprecated but not `unix_timestamp(string date)`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Answer (score 6):

[Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions): `date_sub(date/timestamp/string startdate, tinyint/smallint/int days)`, Subtracts a number of days to date

```
date_sub(current_timestamp(), 10)
```

Format to '`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`'

```
date_format(date_sub(current_timestamp(), 10),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Alternatively,you can also use `date_add(date/timestamp/string startdate, tinyint/smallint/int days)`, Adds a number of days to date

```
date_add(current_timestamp(), -10)
```

Comment: This will return a string or date object. I would like to get a string of the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: @DineshRaj Use date_format(date/timestamp/string ts, string fmt) to format it to your requirement.

Comment: This is helpful too. Thanks!